# Inferring Pyspark schema

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

When a csv file(or any other) is read into a DataFrame with inferSchema as true, do all the rows of a particular column parsed to infer the schema or just a sample of those?
Example:

```
df = (spark.read.format(file_type)
                          .option("inferSchema", infer_schema)
                          .option("header", first_row_is_header)
                          .option("sep", delimiter)
                          .load(file_path))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per [Spark documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-csv.html#data-source-option) for `inferSchema (default=false)`:

> Infers the input schema automatically from data. It requires one extra
> pass over the data. CSV built-in functions ignore this option.

We can use the option `samplingRatio (default=1.0)` to avoid going through all the data for inferring the schema:

> Defines fraction of rows used for schema inferring. CSV built-in
> functions ignore this option.

Answer (score 0):

The "samplingRatio" is an intelligent way to avoid scanning all the rows for the schema infer.

Syntax to do the same while reading a csv

```
df = (
spark.read
.option('header', True)
.option("samplingRatio", 0.001)
.csv(csv_path, inferSchema=True)
```

)